# OpenID connect integration with AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have setup the selfhosted Discourse forum in AWS, where  Login to forum needs to be integrated with AWS Cognito(OpenID), I have followed AWS refernce and below link
https://meta.discourse.org/t/anyone-have-a-working-aws-cognito-configuration-w-ouath2-openid-or-sso/123579/4
and integrated AWS Cognito with Discourse, when i try to login with Discourse application , iam getting redirect mismatch error, below is the screenshot.
Note: i have configured the callback urls and domain name in AWS cognito

CallBackurl:https://mysite/auth/oidc/callback

Domainnurl:https://pstest.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are getting redirect mismatch error because your redirect callback is incorrectly configured in aws cognito. your callback url path should be `/oauth2/idpresponse` so in your case the URL will be - `https://mysite/oauth2/idpresponse`

You will get more info here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-oidc-idp.html